# Django, create table or page just to join all other tables into one and show it. is it possible?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to show info from different tables together in another page or table. But I don't want create another table with duplicate info. Is it possible to Join many tables and show in some admin page?

```
class Answers(models.Model):
    Point = models.ForeignKey(Points, verbose_name="Point", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Answers = models.TextField(verbose_name='Answers', blank=True, null=True)
    Rate = models.TextField(verbose_name='Rate', blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.TextField(verbose_name='Date', blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Answer ' + str(self.Point.En_name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Answers'
        verbose_name = 'Answer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Moderation'
```

You can see class Answers and Text field Answers in it. In this field I have saved answers like:

"answer1
answer2
answer3"

I know it's bad, but there can be many answers, not fixed number, and I need create new table or page where I can see these answers like:

| Question1 | Question2 | Question3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Answer1 | Answer2 | Answer3 |
| 2_Answer2 | 2_Answer2 | 2_Answer3 |

From all info of this model, from all rows. Is it Possible? Or I need duplicate info?

Comment: The quick answer is that you can't join different models into the same queryset but you can access models that are related. Can you provide some example code so that your question can be answered properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, some improvements to your answer model:

```py
class Answer(models.Model): # Django models should be singular, not plural
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, ... # many-to-one relation to Question
    point = models.ForeignKey(Points, # should be 'Point' not 'Points'
    text = models.TextField(... # lower case and shouldn't clash with model name, imo
    rate = models.TextField(... # lower case
    date = models.TextField(... # ...

    ...
```

Set a foreign key relation to your question - this way you can have multiple answers to a single question, or just one.

If you want to get a 'table' of questions and answers then you can do this in views or templates:

```py
questions = Question.objects.all()

for question in questions:
    answers = question.answer_set.all() # get all answers 

    for answer in answers:
        # do stuff
```

```html
{% for question in questions %}
    {{ question }}
    {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
        {{ answer }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello, Im really sorry, can you help more? is it possible to allow edit values in django admin list_display, I mean directly from that admin table page, to make columns allow to edit fields.

Comment: ohh, sorry, sorry I found it - list_editable